# give access to visibility a web tab to a group of people, get data from database to Layout page | Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Desc:**

- I have a web tab and I need to give access to visibility
  to a group of people from the database

**I tried:**

- I am downloading a list of people for whom the bookmark must be covered
- for. exp. single login: AD/ABCD
- I try to send them to a partial view
- and load this partial view into the layout by @Html.Action

**Controller:**

```
using ActionExecutingContext = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutingContext;
using ActionResult = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult;
using Controller = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller;


 public class PrivilegeController : Controller

    {


 private readonly MembersDbContext _membersContext;

        public PrivilegeController(MemebersDbContext  membersDbContext)
        {
            _membersContext= membersContext;
        }


[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Header(string section)
        {
            var listOfManagers = _membersContext. Members.Select(x => x.Adlogin).Distinct().ToList();

            ViewData["listManager"] = listOfManagers;

            return PartialView("_toDevLayout");
        }
}
```

**PartialView:** _toDevLayout

**Layout:** _TrueLayout

```
 @Html.Action("Header", "Privilege")
```

**what is wrong?**

- I got an error in my project that html.action does not exist (version mvc / core 3.1 too high)
- I need to find a different solution

  > Cannot resolve symbol 'Action'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use this in your layout page directly and use list of managers as required.

```
enter code here-> @{var listOfManagers = _membersContext. Members.Select(x => x.Adlogin).Distinct().ToList();}
```